# How to save or print receiverStream data in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Im using the below custom receiver to consume data from Rabbitmq in Spark-Scala.

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.RabbitMQUtils
    import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader}
    import java.net.Socket
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
    import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.{InputDStream, ReceiverInputDStream}
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.streaming._
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver._
    import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
    import org.apache.spark._
    import org.apache.spark.streaming._
    import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    
                    val host = "10.*.*.*"
                    val port = "5**"
                    val queueName = "test"
                    val vHost = "sd"
                    val userName = "user1"
                    val password = "***"
    
                  var batchInterval = Seconds(500)
                  var ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, batchInterval)
                    val receiverStream = RabbitMQUtils.createStream(ssc, Map(
                            "host" -> host,
                            "port" -> port,
                            "queueName" -> queueName,
                            "vHost" -> vHost,
                            "userName" -> userName,
                            "password" -> password
                    ))
                    
                    receiverStream.start()
                    println("started receiverStream")
                    
                    ssc.start()
                    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

How to print the receiverstream data and later save the file to any specific location.
Could someone please assist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to print the stream data with:

```
receiverStream
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("complete")
  .format("console")
  .start()
```

Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#quick-example

You can save to parquet (or other) files with:

```
receiverStream
  .writeStream
  .format("parquet") // can be "orc", "json", "csv", etc.
  .option("path", "path/to/destination/dir")
  .start()
```

See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks

Comment: thanks for the reply. I get the below error.  error: value writeStream is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream[String]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value writeStream'?
  .writeStream